# Why can't rails app on passenger find database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, nginx, vagrant, passenger

I'm trying to create a staging environment for a rails app using vagrant on a windows machine. To get it as close as I can to a production environment, I've installed passenger with nginx. However when I try to use the app, I get the following error:

```
FATAL:  database "my_database" does not exist (PG::ConnectionBad)
```

The rails database configuration works for rake tasks. It has been migrated, seeded and sample data loaded. It definitely exists, and connects if I run the app directly with `rails s`. I'm only having this problem when trying to run it with passenger.

I am completely stumped and too inexperienced with vagrant, passenger and nginx too have any idea on how to approach solving this or what information to provide that might be relevant. Please tell me if more information is necessary and I will update the question. Thankyou

Comment: i think passenger is starting the app in the wrong environment, or maybe you created the database in the wrong environment, try prepending `RAILS_ENV` to your commands, for example `RAILS_ENV=production bin/rake db:setup`

Comment: Thanks. That's a good idea, but I think I'm using staging environment for both. I've put `export RAILS_ENV=staging` in .bashrc and I've put `passenger_app_env staging;` in nginx.conf in the http bit. But I'll double check to make sure.

Comment: Seems like you were right! The .bashrc must not be working like I think it should, but I can look into that myself. Thanks Mohammad.

Comment: use `~/.profile` for the env variables instead of `~/.bashrc` because the server is not starting in a logged in session, so bashrc won't get sourced, but profile will